# How to Add a Recordtype in a custom Lightning Component

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, lightning

I have Apex Class from where I am getting the result correctly but i am not sure how to set the record type in the controller.

It is working fine with the Static Values, Please help

**Apex Class Code:**

```
 @auraEnabled
    public static Requests__c createRequestLeave(Date StartDate, Date EndDate, String Description,string Status, string EmployeeID, string RecordType){
        Requests__c req = new Requests__c();
        req.Employees__c=EmployeeID ;
        req.RecordTypeId=RecordType;
        req.Start_Date__c = StartDate;
        req.End_Date__c = EndDate;
    req.Status__c = Status;
    req.Description__c = Description;
    insert req;
    return req;
}

@auraEnabled
public static RecordType getRecordType() {
    RecordType RecType = [Select Id From RecordType  Where SobjectType = 'Requests__c' and DeveloperName = 'Medical_Card'];
    System.Debug('-----vvv------'+RecType);
    return RecType;
}
```

**Controller:**

```
    insertRequest : function(component, event, helper) {
       // '012B0000000Cwv0IAC'
    var action = component.get("c.createRequestLeave");
    var RectypeID = component.get("c.getRecordType");
    var request = component.get("v.request"); 
    action.setParams({
        "RecordType" : component.get("c.getRecordType"),
        "StartDate" : request.Start_Date__c,
        "Status" : request.Status__c,
        "Description" : request.Description__c,
        "EmployeeID" : 'a08B0000004VQFLIA4'
    });
        console.log("------vvvvvvvv----------"+RectypeID);
    action.setCallback(this, function(response){
       //alert('----------eeeeee-------------'+RectypeID;)
        if(response.getState()==="SUCCESS" && component.isValid()) {
            component.set("v.createView",false);
            $A.get("e.c:RequestClickEvent").setParams({"new":false,"request":component.get("v.request")}).fire();
        $A.get("e.force:showToast").setParams({"message":"New Request Created","duration":"2500"}).fire();
        helper.toggleView(component, "none");
        }
    });

    $A.enqueueAction(action);
},
```

Answer (score 2):

**Firstly you cannot set like this**

<s>"RecordType" : component.get("c.getRecordType"),</s>

First you need to get Record type from apex and set it to another attribute and you can do another **insertRequest** action.

**In controller:**

```
 ({
        getrectype : function(cmp,event,helper) {

            // in the server-side controller
            var action = cmp.get("c.getRecordType");

            // Create a callback that is executed after the server-side action returns
            action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
                var state = response.getState();
          if (cmp.isValid() && state === "SUCCESS") {
    //store it in another attribute 
                 component.set("v.recordtype",response.getReturnValue());

                }            
            });
            // $A.enqueueAction adds the server-side action to the queue.
            $A.enqueueAction(action);
        }
    })
```